# How to reset a form that uses "sticky" values

Tags: php, forms, session, sticky

I have a form where I am using `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['myVar']; ?>"` within the input so that the values are "sticky" for purposes of repopulating the values during server side validation, etc.  My question is how do I make the reset button (type="reset") actually reset the form and remove the saved values.  I am looking for a solution that doesn't use javascript *if possible*!  Thanks!

FORM:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <label class="label1" for="name"> Name: </label>
  <input class="input1" type="text" name="name" id="name"  maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="label1" for="email"> Email: </label>
  <input class="input1" type="text" name="email" id="email"  maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="label1" for="message"> Message: </label>
  <textarea class="flat input1" name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?></textarea>
 </li>
</ul>
```

FORM HANDLER:

```
//save user entered values
$_SESSION['name'] = trim($_POST['name']);
$_SESSION['email'] = trim($_POST['email']);
$_SESSION['message'] = trim($_POST['message']);
```

Comment: Any non standard client side interaction is going to be next to impossible to do without JS.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to have an `<input type="clear">` or similar, but you either have to use JavaScript or refresh the page and have the PHP code clear out those variables.

Comment: What @BenGriffiths said. Most websites nowadays operate under the assumption that everyone has JS enabled anyways, including Stack Overflow itself. I think it's a safe assumption too.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want javascript, you would need to reload the page. Make this button a link to reset_session.php, in which you will just write

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "";
$_SESSION['email'] = "";
$_SESSION['message'] = "";
```

and then redirect with header() back to the form. If you would like to stay on a page, you could send an ajax request to the same page ( reset_session.php ) and then update values in inputs.

Comment: This is the only way to do it without JavaScript (requires a page reload).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript for that. Reset will always reset to the original values the form had when the markup loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The Reset button will reset the form to the values inside of the `value` attributes. And that's it. As you populate those values, it will always reset to these values.

If you want to make it reset to blank values, don't populate / pre-fill those values.

Answer (score 0):

if you use only php, you can try with:
 `unset($_SESSION['myVar']);` or `session_destroy();`