# Clear a form that remembers values

Tags: php, html

I have a form that takes some user details, and allows them to upload a file. The file names and information is saved to a csv file.

If the user doesn't fill in all the fields, the form asks them to fill them and try again. I wanted it to remember the values the user had entered, so I set the default value of the form fields using php:

```
value="<?php print $fulltitle;?>"
```

where $fulltitle = $_POST['fulltitle'];

However, if the user submits something unsuccessfully, hitting reset does not clear the form, it returns their previous attempts.

How can I make the reset functionality work? In the reset button I tried to use

```
onclick="<?php $fulltitle='' ?>"
```

but it seems to have no effect, I guess because the PHP is already processed by the time you hit reset.

Anyone got any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the help, I solved this with a simple reload as suggested.
For anyone looking for an answer to the problem:

In place of a reset button I put:

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="resetform.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>
```

In the file resetform.php I have:

```
<?php
$firstname = '' ;
$lastname = '' ;
$fulltitle = '' ;
$email = '' ;
// etc.

header("Location: submitfile.php");
?>
```

where submitfile.php is the form

/EDIT

---

Trimmed code follows...

Header:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$message = false;

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

//user input with commas and < stripped:
    $firstname = str_replace("<","",str_replace(",",";",$_POST['firstname']));

//if values missing, dont process:
    if(empty($firstname)){
        $message =  '<span style="color:red;text-align:center;">Please complete all required(*) fields,<br />and check the file has been selected correctly.</span>';
        $aClass = 'errorClass';
    }

else {
    //return data array cvsData from user input

    $cvsData = $firstname
    fwrite($fp,$cvsData);
    fclose($fp);
    //reset form
    $firstname = '' ;           
    $message = '<span style="color:blue;text-align:center;">Submission successful, thank you.</span>'; 
    }

}
//if page reloaded, clear form:
else {
    $firstname = '' ;
    }

?>
```

Body:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<table>
<?php
if ($message != false)
    {
    print "<tr><td colspan='2'><span align='center'>" . $message . "</span></td></tr>";
    }
?>  

<tr>
    <td width="200"><span class="texto">*First Name(s)</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php print $firstname;?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a perfect dupe of this somewhere. But in the meantime, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001844/how-to-reset-a-form-that-uses-sticky-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Comment: Sorry for dupe, I tried but couldn't ask the question well enough in google terms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting reset will just reset the form to it's original values. In your case it's their original form submission values because that's what you're setting in the `value` attribute. You need to use JavaScript to delete the form values completely if you want to present the user a blank form.

Here's a JavaScript snippet that should do it:

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {

    tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        switch(tags[i].type) {
            case 'password':
            case 'text':
                tags[i].value = '';
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                tags[i].checked = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if(tags[i].type == 'select-one') {
            tags[i].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            for(j = 0; j < tags[i].options.length; j++) {
                tags[i].options[j].selected = false;
            }
        }
    }

    tags = ele.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i].value = '';
    }

}
```

Then put this in your reset button:

```
onclick="clear_form_elements(this.form[0])"
```

Comment: Thanks, would I call the function using the reset button "onclick" property or is there a better way?

Comment: The other option is just to reload the page (and have PHP output it in its original form).

Comment: Something like this? 

<input type="reset" onclick="javascript:history.go(0)">

Comment: @ralph346526 I put the snippet for your reset button in my answer. I haven't written "real" javascript in a while so if it doesn't work just let me know and I'll correct it. Both  NullUserException and ralph346526's answers are good ideas as well and are worth considering.

Comment: updated question with a solution that avoids java but requires a page reload. Thanks everyone!